# I need to concate statements from three columns for each group condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to build a dataframe from one dataframe where

My current data frame is

```
col1 col2 col3 
a      a1   abc
a      a1   def
a      a2   ijk
a      a2   xyz
a      a2   fgh
b      b1   123
b      b2   456
b      b1   789
b      b2   xua
```

My output should be:

```
col1 col2 col3 
a      a1   abc.def.ijk
a      a1   
a      a1   
a      a2   xyz.fgh
a      a2
b      b1   123.789
b      b2   456.xua
b      b1   
b      b2
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not care about duplicates use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `join`:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('.'.join)
print (df)
  col1 col2         col3
0    a   a1      abc.def
1    a   a1      abc.def
2    a   a2  ijk.xyz.fgh
3    a   a2  ijk.xyz.fgh
4    a   a2  ijk.xyz.fgh
5    b   b1      123.789
6    b   b2      456.xua
7    b   b1      123.789
8    b   b2      456.xua
```

If want avoid duplicates add [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
m = df.duplicated(['col1','col2'])
df['col3'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('.'.join).mask(m, '')
print (df)
  col1 col2         col3
0    a   a1      abc.def
1    a   a1             
2    a   a2  ijk.xyz.fgh
3    a   a2             
4    a   a2             
5    b   b1      123.789
6    b   b2      456.xua
7    b   b1             
8    b   b2
```